Why use alias template with unused and noname parameter?
I am trying to read the source code of xhash from MSVC for the curiosity of the underhood of unordered_map, and I met a template structure as below.
template <class _Kty, class _Hasher, class _Keyeq, class = void>
struct _Uhash_choose_transparency {
    // transparency selector for non-transparent hashed containers
    template <class>
    using _Deduce_key = const _Kty&;
};

What puzzles me is the definition of _Deduce_key.
I know it is an alias template, but, as the template parameter is never used, why should it be defined as a template alias rather than a raw alias?
Like why it cannot be defined as below:
using _Deduce_key = const _Kty&;

I sincerely appreciate any keywords or links.

Related/dupe: Why can templated aliases of anonymous struct/class-es not be defined directly?

thank you @user12002570 but that seems not to be duplicated with this one. Pls allow me to make a rough brief for those who met this post: that post discussed restriction and motivation of defining a structure as a template alias but gives few clues about what the noname-parameter is for.

Yup, it is related but not a dupe. That's why I didn't close it and only posted a comment.

Because the specialized version of _Uhash_choose_transparency::_Deduce_key uses template parameter. Without this, you cannot use template parameter in places where you are using _Deduce_key.

@kakkoko thank you! So can I consider it as a compatible or historical rationale?

@XavierZ. C++20 introduces heterogeneous lookup for unordered containers. Normally, member functions of these containers, such as find(), take the key type of container as an argument, but when heterogenous lookup is enabled, it is possible to give various types as arguments. I have not checked in detail, but giving _Deduce_key a template parameter is probably an implementation trick to achieve this.
